# new operator unable to allocate memory

Tags: c++

In my C++ program I am required to handle large amount of information. I'm storing this large information in a structure. the structure is..

```
struct xlsmain
{
    struct sub_parts_of_interface sub_parts[200];
    string name;
    int no_of_subparts;
};

struct sub_parts_of_interface
{
    struct pio_subparts pio[10];
    string name_of_interface;
    string direction; 
    string partition;
    int no_of_ports;
};

struct pio_subparts
{
    struct corners corner[32]; 
    string pio_name;     
};

struct corners
{
    struct file_structure merging_files[50];
    string corner_name;
    int merginf_files_num;
};

struct file_structure
{
    string file_name;
    string file_type;
    struct reportspecs report[20];
};
```

I'm using new operator to allocate memory to it

```
struct xlsmain *interface = new xlsmain[60];
```

On running the program `std::bad_alloc error` is shown. Plese help!

Comment: AFAIK there's no `new` operator in C.

Comment: Your *"C program"* probably won't even compile. The case would be different for a C++ program, though.

Comment: Your code looks like pure C (with some string in there), you should use malloc instead of new.
If you want to use new then your struct should be transformed to a class (and then it's going to look like C++)

Comment: @zakkak Well, no need to transform it into a class (which would most probably invalidate his code, anyway, making all the variables private). But you're at least partly right in that the usage of `struct` inside of variable declarations is unneccessary in C++.

Comment: @zakkak Both bad_alloc and string are C++. The code is along way from pure C.

Comment: @ChristianRau, i am not that familiar with C++ so i guess you are right about the usage of new. What i wanted to point out is that this code doesn't look like C++ at all :)
Anyhow the problem seems to be that he is trying to allocate too much memory with this struct "recursion"

Comment: For a quick test if you're running out of memory, you could [download some additional RAM](http://www.downloadmoreram.com/) and post if it works with more memory.

Comment: @john, bad_alloc is a runtime error so it doesn't have to do with the source code, so i guess you mean new and string are C++. Actually those two are not that far from C, for a newbie string is something that every language should have, also it could be a typedef char* string;. Finally the usage of new instead of malloc is another newbie step when transitioning from C to C++.

Comment: @zakkak Yes bad_alloc is a run time exception thrown by the C++ standard library.

Comment: @zakkak Yeah, but still the code compiles, so he definitely uses C++, no matter what he intended to use.

Comment: @john yes but how does a program connect to a standard library? Through linking, which means that he compiled and linked his code with g++ and because there is a new in the code and he is trying to allocate the universe he gets this error. That doesn't say much about the style of his code. What i am saying is that the code looks like C, not that it's not C++, actually C is C++... Whatever we are off topic :)

Comment: @zakkak Granted, it's C++ code written in a C style.

Comment: @zakkak That is indeed correct (the looks like thing). Still no need to recommend him to make it even more C-ish (by using `malloc`), since that won't change anything in the fact that he uses C++ already. So the second advice from your initial comment should be the only one given (well ok, in a revised version eliminating the need to transform each struct into a class).

Answer (score 12):

You are trying to allocate 60 `xlsmain` which contain 12,000 `sub_parts_of_interface` which contain 120,000 `pio_subparts` which contain 3,840,000 `corners` which contain 192,000,000 `file_structure` which contain 3,840,000,000 `reportspecs`, and you have not shown the definition of `reportspecs`. So you are trying to allocate 3.8 billion of something and are running out of memory.

That is because the system you are running on does not have enough memory to hold the objects you are trying to allocate.

If those structures contain arrays because the structures might hold those objects, but they usually do not contain the maximums, then get rid of the arrays and replace them `std::vector` (in C++) or pointers (in C or C++). With either method, you will use just space for the actual objects needed plus some accounting overhead, instead of using space for the maximum theoretically possible. `std::vector` allows you to add elements as needed, and the `std::vector` application will take care of allocating the needed memory. With pointers, you would have to allocate and free the space yourself.

Comment: +1. It's a lot worse than 64 million because of all that auxiliary stuff. If `reportspec` contains but one `char`, `60*sizeof(xlsmain)` is 7.2 gigabytes, which is already huge. If sizeof(`reportspec`) is a bit larger, say 128 bytes, `60*sizeof(xlsmain)` becomes a whopping 460.7 gig.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Yes, it took me a few revisions to get all the levels accounted for correctly. There are 3.8 billion objects just in those shown! If the program is running on a 32-bit system, it probably overflowed the size type and was just lucky it got a value that reported unable to allocate memory, instead of allocating a small amount and overrunning it. `bad_alloc` is the wrong exception for this; it should be `very_bad_alloc`.

Comment: I would recommend using `std::vector` as it does all the memory management (re-allocation, destruction etc) for you, with only a small overhead.

Comment: @EricPostpischil +1 for the joke

Comment: thank you for the suggestions and the figures. but with vectors i am not able to store data into nested structure like this

Comment: @Cprog: What prevents you from storing data in vectors in nested structures?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple enough. You haven't got enough memory. Either buy some more memory or redesign your code. I would suggest that your replace your arrays with zero length vectors. That way you only need to grow the vectors to the size you actually need, instead of having a fixed size always. That will use less memory and be more flexible as well. For instance

```
  struct pio_subparts
   {
    vector<corners> corner; 
    string pio_name;     
   };
```

More precise advice isn't possible without knowing exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: In this case the problem is in syntax and general understanding of C/C++ than running out of memory

Comment: @jhonkola He's getting a std::bad_alloc exception therefore, whatever the issues with the code he has posted, he has successfully compiled and run a C++ program. He's also trying to allocate a very large structure. I think he's running out of memory.

Comment: The bit about not having enough memory is very likely correct. ,It's allocting 192,000,000 file structures each of which contains string and *20* copies of whatever reportspecs is.

Comment: If only a small number of the array slots are used then vectors might use less memory...

Comment: Buying more memory is not an option. The only option is to redesign the code.

Comment: @David Hammen exactly, the structure probably does not even fit entirely into the memory of a 32 bit system.

Answer (score 0):

@H2CO3 is right.

In pure C use something like this:
http://www.elook.org/programming/c/malloc.html

Comment: But malloc will not solve the underlying problem. Her will get NULL because of memory exhaustion. The underlying problem is that the structure is to bit to fit into memory.

Comment: Yes, @rioki, you are completely right. When I posted this comment it was "In my C program", not in my "In my C++ program"... and all this structs, not classes. So I did't read code meticulously. Thanks to Eric Postpischil, he was more careful. =)